# ReferenceError: RenderNewMessage is not defined

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am currently working on a project where i want a function to be called at bottom of my page. i have jquery included in my project and it keeps throwing me this weird error. It might be simple but i can't figure it out and i've searched a bit here on stack for similar problems but none of the solutions work. - and yes, all the scripting pages are loaded before the function call

**CLIENT PAGE**

```
 echo "<script type='text/javascript'> window.onload = function(){ RenderNewMessage('new/".replaceSpace($user->profile(1, [ "DataType" => "username" ] ))."'); } </script>";
```

**JS PAGE**

```
function RenderNewMessage(data){
        alert(data);
        //renderMessages(data.split(","));
    }
```

**ERROR**

```
ReferenceError: RenderNewMessage is not defined
```